# Aligning Images with Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to have 1 image on the top with 2 images below it spanning half the width of the image on top. The problem I'm encountering are aligning issues with the 2 images in which they don't fit nicely below the top image but spaced perfectly to the sides. I'm trying to have the 2 images be below the top image perfectly aligned in the center with no spaces below. As I shrink the window, that is when it looks like I want it to on a full screen except without the spaces. I also want them perfectly aligned in the center of the screen.

https://jsfiddle.net/voryuja8/

```css
.first {
  display: flex;
}

.first img {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.second {
  display: flex;
}

.second img {
  margin: auto;
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <img src="https://sarahannephoto.files.wordpress.com/2015/01/devyn_015.jpg?w=1008" alt="">
</div>

<div class="second">
  <img src="http://preen.inquirer.net/files/2016/05/preen-emily-oberg-complex-e1463660455785.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="http://preen.inquirer.net/files/2016/05/preen-emily-oberg-complex-e1463660455785.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `margin:auto` from the images and use `justify-content: center` in the flex containers.

```css
.first {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.first img {
  max-width: 800px;
}

.second {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.second img {
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <img src="https://sarahannephoto.files.wordpress.com/2015/01/devyn_015.jpg?w=1008" alt="">
</div>

<div class="second">
  <img src="http://preen.inquirer.net/files/2016/05/preen-emily-oberg-complex-e1463660455785.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="http://preen.inquirer.net/files/2016/05/preen-emily-oberg-complex-e1463660455785.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit better, as it doesn't rely on setting pixel values for anything: https://jsfiddle.net/voryuja8/1/

HTML:
    [image]

```
<div class="second">
  <div class="flex-child">
     <img src="http://preen.inquirer.net/files/2016/05/preen-emily-oberg-complex-e1463660455785.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="flex-child">
     <img src="http://preen.inquirer.net/files/2016/05/preen-emily-oberg-complex-e1463660455785.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.second {
    display: flex;
}

.flex-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
```

Comment: I like this angle too but when the screen resize gets larger, the top images doesn't stick with the bottom two images. @jas7457